# Accesing only key names of json using jsonPath

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I have a simple question, say I have the following json

```
{
   "ALPHA":[
      ....
   ],
   "BETA":[
     ....
   ],
   "GAMMA":[
     .....
   ]
}
```

how do I access the subroot elements, I mean just the names:  `"ALPHA","BETA","GAMMA"` using jsonPath? **Be aware that I mean their names not their array!!!**

I tried `jsonPath("$[*]", ...)` but it doesn't work, any sugesstions?

Comment: Seems your have put the wrong tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Raymond Choi, it should also work.

But based on your answer, that I should use the function `keys()`, I search a lit bit more and I found that `jsonPath` indeed has his own function.

So the solution to my question is simple:

`jsonPath("$.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson*. Just one function `keys()` can do the job.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "   \"ALPHA\":[" +
    "      1,2,3,4" +
    "   ]," +
    "   \"BETA\":[" +
    "     5,6,7" +
    "   ]," +
    "   \"GAMMA\":[" +
    "     8,9" +
    "   ]" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("keys()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ "ALPHA", "BETA", "GAMMA" ]
```